# sed command on Solaris

Tags: unix, sed, solaris, quoting

I am trying to execute below command to replace variables in SQL with values passed from shell script but every time I am getting the same error as

> sed: command garbled

```
sed -e 's/${BATCH_ID}/'${BATCH_ID}'/g; s/${LOAD_DATE}/TO_DATE\('"'"${LOAD_DATE}"'","'"YYYY-MM-DD"'"\)'/g' ${sqlFile}  >> ${SQL_DIR}/fmv_media_premise_ucg_update_temp.sql
```

Please can you help me in this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you should learn how and when to use quotes and single-quotes in bash.

Comment: Could you please explain what mistake have I done in using quotes above?

Comment: I could, but it would be easier if you would simply read one of the thousands of articles regarding this topic on the internet.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks. I have $sqlfile which is an insert statement and I have to replace variables in that sql file with the values I am passing from Unix script.

Comment: Does your date or batch ID have a slash in it?  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and post one that allows us to see the problem you see.

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted your sed command in the following way:

```
sed -e "s/\${BATCH_ID}/${BATCH_ID}/g; s/\${LOAD_DATE}/TO_DATE(${LOAD_DATE},'YYYY-MM-DD')/g" ${sqlFile}  >> ${SQL_DIR}/fmv_media_premise_ucg_update_temp.sql
```

It will replace all occurrences of ${BATCH_ID} by the value contained in your BATCH_ID variable and change all ${LOAD_DATE} by the TO_DATE( value contained in LOAD_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), I hope this helps you! Cheers

One remark your are appending the output of your sed command to the fmv_media_premise_ucg_update_temp.sql file, are you sure you should not completely replace it?  If it is the case just use > instead of >>

Comment: > does not matter here because every time I am deleting the temp file before running this script

Comment: could you please give me some examples of the values contained in BATCH_ID and LOAD_DATE? I am pretty sure they contain some character that sed uses internally causing your error... 
If it this the case, before calling sed with the variables you should create a function that would escape all those characters using "\"

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `envsubst`? This will provide you with

```
envsubst < "${sqlFile}"
```

That will be better than

```
source <(echo "echo \"$(< ${sqlfile})\"")
```

The last one will expand more things.